# How to open the 'Projects' panel in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

In Netbeans, to the top left of where the code is, there used to be two panels, one called 'Projects' where you could click a project name to open a tree of all the directories and files in it, and you could double click a file to edit it.

Below it is the navigation panel which shows the class names, methods, etc contained in the file you're viewing.

I accidently clicked the close button on the projects panel and can't figure out how to get it to open again, any ideas?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

In Netbeans 6.8 on Windows, going to `Window` -> `Projects` brings it back for me.  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> works as the shortcut.

Comment: Had the same issue and did this. It did bring back the Projects window but when i open a file from the Projects window it opens in the same pane as the Projects window. @Tareq Mahmood answer solved it for me.

Comment: Had the same issue. Resetting did not work either. But Ctrl+Shift+1 did the trick for me.

Comment: And Window → Navigator (Ctrl+7) gives the code navigation window the question also mentions.

Comment: Also, you can bring up, e.g. the `Services` panel if you accidentally closed it, and also some other stuff that isn't there by default.

Answer (score 68):

Click Window > Reset Windows will give you back the old state of all windows!

Comment: Thanks! I opened NetBeans to find the left vertical toolbar empty. When I opened the Projects tab by `Window → Projects`, it opened a tab like any other file, and I couldn't get it to dock vertically again. This fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

just go to Window in menu bar and select Projects

```
 Window -> Projects
```

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans 8.2 Go to Window->Navigator in menu bar or press Ctrl+7 and select Projects 
it will open a folder as work space .