# Netbeans IDE Project Window not visible

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

The project window within Netbeans IDE is not being displayed. I tried bunch of different things, but the `Project` window does not open at all.

Things I already tried:

- Tried with multiple version of Netbeans and JDE, currently using Netbeans IDE 8.2 on MAC.
- Tried to reset windows using `Reset Windows`, `cmd 1`, open existing project,
  create new project. But still the project window does not open within
  Netbeans IDE.

I made a clean install on MAC with different version of Netbeans, but the issue remains in all. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251202/how-to-open-the-projects-panel-in-netbeans) perhaps.

Comment: Already tried this. @SandeepRandhawa

Comment: A few thoughts: [1] Instead of **cmd 1** use **Window -> Projects** to open the **Projects** window. [2] Create a new project. That should open the **Projects** window if it is not already open. [3] If you still don't have a **Projects** window then open the NetBeans log file using **View -> IDE Log** and look for any relevant error messages.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried running it with java 8? If you're using java 9 or 10, you don't get a Projects window because NB 8.2 isn't compatible with them.

There's more info at [How can I install Netbeans with JDK 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502600/how-can-i-install-netbeans-with-jdk-10).

Answer (score 7):

This is a known issue in Netbeans 8.2. It happened to me when I upgraded my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04. The root cause is that the java version was upgraded to 11 along with the OS.

You can fix this by doing one of the following:

- Change the default jdk/jre version in the OS to `java 8`.
- Change the jdk version to 8 in Netbeans by changing its configuration (etc/netbeans.conf). The configuration name is `netbeans_jdkhome`

Answer (score 0):

like @rocko say, (I don't have 'add comment' right yet, so answer this frame )
I encounter same problem in NB 12.0 .

**DEAL)   ...my action**

I changed JDK1.8 → JDK 11 setting in netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf
After launch NB,  then open new project.
Project tree appeared and usable again.

```
#netbeans_jdkhome="C:\xxx\jdk1.8.0_242"
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\xxx\jdk11.0.3_7"
```

Environment

- win10
- corretto

Answer (score 0):

To see projects or files when they disappear on NetBeans, just follow the steps in the image below.

[image: sample_image]